# How to perform cube root transformation in given dataframe in R

Tags: r

I already have a dataframe that needed to import from desktop. I first read file and then perform cube root transformation, but it told me wrong when I do the transformation. What is the problem? The dataframe include word and number.

```r
# Import data frame
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/yinc1/Desktop/test_R.csv", header = TRUE)
head(df)


# Perform cube root transformation 
df_cube_root <- df^(1/3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Cynthia, welcome to SO! I guess you just need to use the `sqrt()` function like this: `df_cube_root <- cbind(df[1], sqrt(df[,2:13]))` Cheers

Comment: Hi lovalery, thank you for your code! But I want the cube root of data: ^(1/3), not ^(1/2). How to change code to get cube root transformation?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Oh sorry, I need to go to sleep!!! So, try this: `df_cube_root <- cbind(df[1], df[,2:13]^(1/3))` Cheers

Comment: May I ask this code `df[1]` stand for what? I am curious the "1" means first row or column? Cheers.

Comment: In the case of a `dataframe`, `df[1]` is equivalent to `df[,1, drop=FALSE]`: they both select the first column and return it as a data.frame; `df[,1]` is equivalent to `df[[1]]`: they also both select the first column but return an atomic vector. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Greetings! Please share a reproducible dataset as shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to reference the specific column of the data you wish to transform.

For example, for column y of df:

```
df_cube_root <- df$y^(1/3)
```

Comment: df_cube_root <- df[2:148, 2:149]^(1/3)
#Is this time correct?

Comment: If you want to select all rows and all columns of the data frame, I believe `df_cube_root <- df[]^(1/3)` will work

Comment: Thanks Gui, the code works when I set `header = FALSE`.